# How to convert list to graph object in R?

Tags: r, list, graph, igraph, adjacency-list

I have adjacency list as shown here- `dput(data)`

```
list(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 22L, 
32L), c(1L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 31L), c(2L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 
14L, 28L, 29L, 33L), c(1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 13L), c(1L, 7L, 11L), 
    c(1L, 11L, 17L), c(5L, 6L, 17L), c(1L, 3L, 4L), c(1L, 3L, 
    31L, 34L), c(3L, 34L, 33L), c(1L, 5L, 6L), c(1L, 32L, 23L
    ), c(1L, 4L, 2L), c(1L, 2L, 4L, 34L), c(33L, 34L, 29L), c(33L, 
    34L, 33L), c(6L, 7L, 19L), c(1L, 2L, 10L), c(33L, 34L, 14L
    ), c(1L, 2L, 34L), c(33L, 34L, 26L), c(1L, 2L, 15L), c(33L, 
    34L, 6L), c(26L, 28L, 33L, 34L), c(26L, 28L, 32L), c(24L, 
    25L, 32L), c(30L, 34L, 20L), c(3L, 24L, 34L), c(3L, 32L, 
    34L), c(24L, 27L, 33L), c(9L, 33L, 34L), c(1L, 25L, 26L, 
    33L), c(3L, 9L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 24L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 34L
    ), c(9L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 29L, 
    30L, 31L, 32L, 33L))
```

The list is similar to adjacency list and I wanted to convert it into igraph object in R. I have tried using
  `graph_from_data_frame(data, directed = FALSE, vertices = NULL)`
but it is not working. I have also tried

```
graph_from_adj_list(data,mode="all",duplicate=FALSE)
```

but this is giving wrong graph. For example `1-> 2,3,5,6` should have edges as `1->2,1->3,1->5,1-6`; but it is giving random output as `1->3,2->5,3->6,2->6` ...likewise.
 Any idea, how this could be done in R?

Comment: Using `mode="out"` perhaps gives expected graph. `g=graph_from_adj_list(lst, mode="out", duplicate=FALSE) ; as_adj_list(g, mode="out")`

Comment: The question suggests that the graph should be undirected. Could you explain what is wrong with the result of `graph_from_adj_list(data,mode="all",duplicate=FALSE)`

Comment: `mode="out"` gives the same output graph.

Comment: @tfc the edges are constructed within the nodes. For example 1-> 2,3,5,6 should have edges as 1->2,1->3,1->5,1-6;  but it is giving random output as 1->3,2->5,3->6,2->6 ...likewise

Comment: kumar: when i execute the commands in my first comment, the adj_list returns the input list suggesting that they are the same: `g=graph_from_adj_list(lst, mode="out", duplicate=FALSE) ; al=as_adj_list(g, mode="out") ;
all(sapply(seq(lst), function(xx) all.equal(sort(as.numeric(lst[[xx]])), sort(as.numeric(al[[xx]])))))`

Comment: @user20650 could you please explain the function in your last comment

Comment: The last command just compares your input list (lst) with the edge list (al) produced from as_adj_list. It returns TRUE, meaning they are the same. Maybe this is easier to see `all.equal(lapply(lst,sort), lapply(al, as.numeric))`